# The normalized chain complex of a simplicial set

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, simplicial-stuff

The paper The Geometry of Rewriting Systems, by K. Brown, mentions the notion of a normalized chain complex associated to a simplicial set. How is this complex defined? (and perharps the non-normalized chain complex as well)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goerss and Jardine define this in their book *Simplicial Homotopy Theory*, chapter III, section 2. It is also defined at [the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Moore+complex). Both define it for simplicial groups, Goerss and Jardine just for simplicial abelian groups. These two sources use slightly different conventions.

Let $A$ be a simplicial abelian group. Goerss and Jardine define the normalized chain complex $NA$ by
$$
NA_n = \bigcap_{i=0}^{n-1} \ker(d_i), \quad \partial = (-1)^n d_n
$$
while on nLab they use
$$
NA_n = \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} \ker(d_i), \quad \partial = d_0
$$
A standard result (Theorem 2.1 in Goerss and Jardine) is that $NA$ is isomorphic to the chain complex obtained by modding out by the subgroup generated by the degeneracies.

Comment: Is the construction shown in the picture really a simplicial monoid? The problem I see is that the "middle" face operators $d_1(m_1,\dots,m_n)m = (m_1,\dots,m_im_{i+1},\dots, m_n) m$ are not monoid homomorphisms, unless $M$ is commutative. That means the given construction yields only a simplicial set, which doesn't allow us to talk about its Moore complex anymore.

Comment: Maybe there is some shorthand going on: if you have a simplicial set $X$, you can form a simplicial abelian group by taking the free abelian group on $X_n$ in dimension $n$. Maybe that's what Brown is doing.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, specially considering how he says that the Moore complex is essentially the same as the bar resolution.